# Get the the in time and out time of employee in Full Calendar according to the user id selected in drop down list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, fullcalendar

I want to display **in time** and **out time** of the user in full calendar. Each and every user has different **in time** and **out time**. And the user id is selected in drop down. Right now I'm getting the drop down which is binded with the **user name** and **user id** so I have to bind the **login time** and **logout time** of the user to the **calendar**.This is my code where i bind the drop down with data. **This is my controller** code for binding the drop down with the user id and  user name.

```
public ActionResult AttendanceScreen()
{
List<SelectListItem> userList = Getuser();
return View(userList);
}
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AttendanceScreen(string ddlCustomers)
{
List<SelectListItem> userList = Getuser();
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ddlCustomers))
{
SelectListItem selectedItem = userList.Find(p => p.Value == ddlCustomers);
ViewBag.Message = "Calender for Name: " + selectedItem.Text;
ViewBag.Message += "\\nID: " + selectedItem.Value;
}
return View(userList);
}
private static List<SelectListItem> Getuser()
{
RegMVCEntities entities = new RegMVCEntities();
List<SelectListItem> customerList = (from p in entities.tblRegistrations.AsEnumerable()
select new SelectListItem
{
Text = p.FName,
Value = p.UserId.ToString()
}).ToList();


//Add Default Item at First Position.
customerList.Insert(0, new SelectListItem { Text = "--Select Employee--", Value = "" });
return customerList;
}
```

**This is my view** for displaying the  user id and  user name as alert.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("AttendanceScreen", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{

@Html.DropDownList("ddlCustomers", Model)
<br />
<br />
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />

}

@if (ViewBag.Message != null)
{
<script type="text/javascript">


window.onload = function () {

alert("@ViewBag.Message");


};
```

**For displaying the calendar the controller code is**

```
public JsonResult GetEvents()
{
using (RegMVCEntities dc = new RegMVCEntities())
{
var events = dc.User_LogTime.ToList();
dc.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
dc.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
return new JsonResult { Data = events, JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet };
}
}
```

**For displaying the calendar the code of my view is**

```
<h2>Calender</h2>
<div id="calender"></div>

<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
<div class="modal-dialog">
<div class="modal-content">
<div class="modal-header">
<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
<h4 class="modal-title"><span id="eventTitle"></span></h4>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
<button id="btnDelete" class="btn btn-default btn-sm pull-right">
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span> Remove
</button>
<button id="btnEdit" class="btn btn-default btn-sm pull-right" style="margin-right:5px;">
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span> Edit
</button>
<p id="pDetails"></p>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>

<div id="myModalSave" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
<div class="modal-dialog">
<div class="modal-content">
<div class="modal-header">
<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
<h4 class="modal-title">Save Event</h4>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
<form class="col-md-12 form-horizontal">
<input type="hidden" id="hdEventID" value="0" />
@*<div class="form-group">
<label>Subject</label>
<input type="text" id="txtSubject" class="form-control" />
</div>*@
<div class="form-group">
<label>LoginTime</label>
<div class="input-group date" id="dtp1">
<input type="text" id="txtStart" class="form-control" />
<span class="input-group-addon">
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
</span>
</div>
</div>
@*<div class="form-group">
<div class="checkbox">
<label><input type="checkbox" id="chkIsFullDay" checked="checked" /> Is Full Day event</label>
</div>
</div>*@
<div class="form-group" id="divEndDate" style="display:none">
<label>LogoutTime</label>
<div class="input-group date" id="dtp2">
<input type="text" id="txtEnd" class="form-control" />
<span class="input-group-addon">
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
</span>
</div>
</div>
@*<div class="form-group">
<label>Description</label>
<textarea id="txtDescription" rows="3" class="form-control"></textarea>
</div>*@
<div class="form-group">
<label>Theme Color</label>
<select id="ddThemeColor" class="form-control">
<option value="">Default</option>
<option value="red">Red</option>
<option value="blue">Blue</option>
<option value="black">Black</option>
<option value="green">Green</option>
</select>
</div>
<button type="button" id="btnSave" class="btn btn-success">Save</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
</form>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>

<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.4.0/fullcalendar.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.4.0/fullcalendar.print.css" rel="stylesheet" media="print" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.47/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
@section Scripts{
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.4.0/fullcalendar.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.47/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
debugger;

var event_array = [];

var selectedEvent = null;
FetchEventAndRenderCalendar();
function FetchEventAndRenderCalendar() {
events = [];
$.ajax({
url: "/Home/GetEvents",
data: "",
type: "GET",
dataType: "json",
async: false,
cache: false,
success: function (data) {
alert("success");

$.each(data, function (i, v) {
event_array.push({
userid: v.UserId,
start: moment(v.LoginTime),
end: moment(v.LogoutTime),

//start: moment(v.start),
//end: v.end != null ? moment(v.end) : null,
//color: v.themecolor,
//allday: v.isfullday
});

})

GenerateCalender(event_array);
},
error: function (error) {
alert('failed');
}
})
}

function GenerateCalender(event_array) {
debugger;
//$('#calender').fullCalendar('destroy');
$('#calender').fullCalendar({
contentHeight: 400,
defaultDate: new Date(),
timeFormat: 'h(:mm)a',
header: {
left: 'prev,next today',
center: 'title',
right: 'month,basicWeek,basicDay,agenda'
},
eventLimit: true,
eventColor: '#378006',
events: event_array,
eventClick: function (calEvent, jsEvent, view) {
selectedEvent = calEvent;
$('#myModal #eventTitle').text(calEvent.userid);
var $description = $('<div/>');
$description.append($('<p/>').html('<b>LoginTime:</b>' + calEvent.logintime.format("DD-MMM-YYYY HH:mm a")));

$description.append($('<p/>').html('<b>LogoutTime:</b>' + calEvent.logouttime.format("DD-MMM-YYYY HH:mm a")));

//$description.append($('<p/>').html('<b>Description:</b>' + calEvent.description));
//$('#myModal #pDetails').empty().html($description);

$('#myModal').modal();
},
//selectable: true,
//select: function (logintime, logouttime) {
// selectedEvent = {
//// userid: 0,
//// logintime: logintime,
//// logouttime: logouttime


//// };
//// openAddEditForm();
//// $('#calendar').fullCalendar('unselect');
////},
////editable: false,
eventDrop: function (event) {
var data = {
UserId: event.userid,
LoginTime: event.logintime.format('DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm A'),
LogoutTime: event.logouttime.format('DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm A')


};
SaveEvent(data);
}

});
}
```

this is the screenshot of my current page

The attendance screen

[image]

**Right I'm just getting the in time and out time in the database as you can see in screenshot but that is for all the user in Database.I just need to update the calendar with in time and out time of  the user id selected in drop down**.

Comment: well first you need to handle the "change" event of your dropdown list, and get the selected value. Then you need to make an ajax call to the GetEvents function and send the user ID with it. Modify your GetEvents function so it optionally accepts an ID and then restricts the query results based on it, if an ID is supplied. Then get the results, remove the existing events from the calendar and add the new ones. Which part of that process was giving you trouble, exactly? You don't seem to have even tried to do it...

Comment: Sorry I'm not that good in ajax.How will I get the user id which is getting selected in drop down in JsonResult GetEvents().I'm facing problem in this. I have tried lots of ways but none of that helps. It would be really helpful if you elaborate your answer @ADyson

Comment: `public JsonResult GetEvents(int id = default(int))` I should think will allow you to receive the ID in your controller, but also allow it to be an optional parameter. The rest you can easily google as well - it's all pretty standard stuff. Do you understand about handling DOM events in JavaScript / jQuery? Do you understand about making ajax requests? If not go and research, now is a good time to learn for yourself, there are lots and lots of tutorials on all these subjects. And then if you're still stuck after, show us what you've tried and explain where you're specifically having a problem

Answer (score 0):

I have done it. It was simple I just needed to use session for getting the user id.This is my code:

```
 public ActionResult AttendanceScreen(string ddlCustomers)
        {
            Session["userid"] = ddlCustomers;

            List<SelectListItem> userList = Getuser();
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ddlCustomers))
            {
                SelectListItem selectedItem = userList.Find(p => p.Value == ddlCustomers);
                ViewBag.Message = "Calender for Name: " + selectedItem.Text;
                ViewBag.Message += "\\nID: " + selectedItem.Value;
            }
            return View(userList);
           // return RedirectToAction("Index", "Nome", new { userid: userid });
        }
 public JsonResult GetEvents()
        {
            string username = User.Identity.Name;
            int isessionid = Convert.ToInt32(Session["userid"]);
            List<SelectListItem> userList = Getuser();
            if (isessionid == 0)
            {
                return null;
            }
            else
            {

                //int userid = int.Parse(username);

                RegMVCEntities svc = new RegMVCEntities();
                svc.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
                svc.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
               // var oCampaigns = svc.User_LogTime;
                var oReturn =
                       (from c in svc.User_LogTime.AsEnumerable()
                        where c.UserId == isessionid
                        select new 
                        {
                            LoginTime = c.LoginTime,
                            Logouttime = c.LogoutTime
                        }).ToList();
                //var events = dc.User_LogTime.ToList();
                //dc.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
                //   dc.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
                return new JsonResult { Data = oReturn.ToList(), JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet };
            }



        }
```